# Has anyone gotten an android phone to reliably USB tether to raspberry pi?

Tags: usb, android

All,

There are a lot of threads on using a old android phone to USB tether to a raspberry pi for internet access.  I am trying to tether a RPi to an android phone to allow passing of MQTT messages to my farm irrigation valves (esp8266 based).  The idea is for me to be able to go out of town for a week or two at a time and have reliable connectivity to trigger my irrigation system.  It is working (Galaxy s4 on Ting wireless, RPi3, Home Assistant), but the phone keeps untethering every few hours.  Would Wifi tethering be more reliable?  Should I root the phone and change operating systems?

Any help would be appreciated.

Montyhp

Comment: `root the phone and change operating systems` ... what alternative would you use?

Answer (score 1):

yes. I have it working stable via USB tethering with a google Nexus 5 phone which is rooted. I send the tethering command via android adb.

```
## /usr/bin/usbtether.sh

#!/bin/sh
adb shell service call connectivity 33 i32 1 s16 text
```

I am running a service:

```
[Unit]
Description=start tethering
Before=network-pre.target
Wants=network-pre.target
Requires=local-fs.target
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
SyslogIdentifier=tether
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
ExecStart=/usr/bin/usbtether.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=network.target
```

when setting it up, I found these resourced helpful:

https://github.com/sclem/pi-tether

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171744/how-can-i-enable-usb-tethering-through-adb